# How to add ocx control which not supports wpf in wpf window?

Tags: wpf, winforms, ocx

I'm new to wpf!

I want to add ocx control in wpf window. Is it possible?

The control I'm using does not support wpf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you!

Step by step guid to host ActiveX control in WPF.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742735(v=vs.110).aspx